# What is the best way to toggle between two different Lit components?

Tags: javascript, button, components, toggle, lit

I am working with Lit components. I want to create two buttons and toggle between two different components. What is the best approach to achieve that?

Comment: Please add an executable StackOverflow Snippet to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way depends on your use case. In this case it is probably the simplest way.

- Use a [reactive property](https://lit.dev/docs/components/properties/) to maintain the state of which component to render. When a button is pressed, this state can change, and a reactive update is scheduled resulting in an efficient template update.
- Have a parent that contains the two buttons and the state of which view to render, and then renders that view.

For more sophisticated component composition setups see [lit.dev documentation on Component Composition](https://lit.dev/docs/composition/component-composition/). There is also a great video by the Lit core team on [Event communication between components](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9mxtnoy9Qw).

Here's a runnable example showing a small example of two buttons toggling between two different components:

```html
<script type="module">
import {html, LitElement} from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/lit/dist@2/core/lit-core.min.js"


class ContainerEl extends LitElement {
  static properties = {
    toggleComponent: {type: Boolean},
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.toggleComponent = false;
  }

  render() {
    // Using a ternary to choose which template to use. Could also
    // do this with an `if` statement.
    const view = this.toggleComponent ?
        html`<view-b></view-b>` : html`<view-a></view-a>`;
    return html`
        <button @click=${() => {this.toggleComponent = false;}}>
          View A
        </button>
        <button @click=${() => {this.toggleComponent = true;}}>
          View B
        </button>
        ${view}
    `;
  }
}

class ViewA extends LitElement {
  render() { return html`<b>Element A</b>`; }
}

class ViewB extends LitElement {
  render() { return html`<i>Element B</i>`; }
}

customElements.define('container-el', ContainerEl);
customElements.define('view-a', ViewA);
customElements.define('view-b', ViewB);
</script>

<container-el></container-el>
```

In specific more complicated cases, the following directives could also be useful (but not in a simple situation such as this one):

- [cache](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/directives/#cache) directive: Caches rendered DOM when changing templates rather than discarding the DOM.
- [guard](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/directives/#guard) directive: Only re-evaluates the template when one of its dependencies changes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. That solution is what I was looking for, I just tested out in my project and everything works as planned.

Comment: I am also trying to add green background-color to the button when button is active. Would you have some great solution to that one? I am trying with styleMap but it's not working as I want it to work.

Comment: Could you make a new question showing how you're using styleMap and I can help there? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74300942/change-button-background-color-when-button-is-clicked-with-lit-components-stylem