# Change button background-color when button is clicked with lit components styleMap

Tags: javascript, button, components, web-component, lit

I toggle between components on button click and I want to show active button when the user has clicked on a button. So backgroundColor of a clicked button should be green, but now when I click on one of the buttons, both buttons became green. How can I solve that so only one active button is green?

```js
   @customElement('my-comp')
    export class myComp extends LitElement {
      static styles = css`
        .buttons-container {
          display: inline-flex;
          width: 100%;
          margin: 20px;
          gap: 20px;
        }
    
        button:active {
          background: green;
        }
    `
    
    @property() toggleComponent: boolean
    
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.toggleComponent = false;
      }
    
      private toggleComponentFunc() {
        this.toggleComponent = !this.toggleComponent
    
      }
    
      render() {
        
        const styles = {
          backgroundColor: this.toggleComponent ? 'lightgreen' : 'red',
    
        };
    
        const view = this.toggleComponent ?
        html`<comp-a></comp-a>` : html`<comp-b></comp-b>`
        return html`
            <div class="buttons-container">
              <button class="button" style=${styleMap(styles)} @click=${() => {this.toggleComponent = false;}}>
                comp A
              </button>
              <button class="button" style=${styleMap(styles)} @click=${() => {this.toggleComponent = true;}}>
                comp B
              </button>
            </div>
    
            ${view}
        `;
    
      }
    }
```

This is the source question: [What is the best way to toggle between two different Lit components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74276251/what-is-the-best-way-to-toggle-between-two-different-lit-components)

Comment: You can add this functionality with pure javascript. It would be simpler too.

Comment: I was wondering if there is some better way with lit components instead

Comment: I don't think so - not everyone understands how to work with lit components, but using pure js would enable many more people to understand your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that both buttons are being passed the same styles.

```js
const styles = {
  backgroundColor: this.toggleComponent ? 'lightgreen' : 'red',
};
```

If `this.toggleComponent` is true, `styles` will contain: `background-color: 'lightgreen';`, and then both buttons appear lightgreen.

A potential solution is to define the two style variants for the two buttons and pass them to the two buttons. Maybe something like:

```
// In render method (only showing changes)

    const stylesBtn1 = {
      backgroundColor: this.toggleComponent ? 'lightgreen' : 'red',
    };
    const stylesBtn2 = {
      backgroundColor: !this.toggleComponent ? 'lightgreen' : 'red',
    };

    return html`
      <button class="button" style=${styleMap(stylesBtn1)}>
        comp A
      </button>
      <button class="button" style=${styleMap(stylesBtn2)}>
        comp B
      </button>
    `;
```

Note that `styleBtn1` uses `this.toggleComponent` and `styleBtn2` uses `!this.toggleComponent`.